# How to Pass Values within HTML Div To PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am developing a forum in php. I have made a "**Reply With Quote**" button under each post and When User Clicks this button, It runs a JQuery Function that gets the text of that post and Put It into the CKEditor and Wrap the Text with a Div having an `id="quote"`. The Text Looks like this after inserting to CKEditor

```
<div id="quote">This is the quoted Text"</div>
```

Normally In Forums the Values are passed in quotes like this

```
[QUOTE=user_name;post_id]This is Quoted Text[/QUOTE]
```

But I am not using BBCode in my forum. So, How can I Pass `user_name` and `post_id` values within my `<div id="quote">` to PHP??

Comment: From where you pick the user_name and post_id?

Comment: Add hidden input fields?

Comment: @AmGates I pick the user_name and post_id from the same post div using JQuery.

Comment: Are doing form submission or submission through ajax ?

Comment: I am submitting through ajax

Answer (score 0):

That button should run an ajax query to pass the form values to your server, before inserting that quote div into the page.

Comment: But there is a Problem with that. I have also provided the facility to Multiquote the Posts. Suppose a user selects three posts as multiquote and press "Reply with Quote" button and all three posts are inserted into the CKEditor with three separate divs, Now Suppose I run an Ajax query that Records the user_name and post_id values of the three quoted posts, but after that if User removes one quoted post from the CKEditor then what? It means I will have to be dependent on which exists in the CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to add a hidden field before inserting the div into the page and obtian user credentials form either session or cookie